# Springboot apps stop responding randomly

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, macos

I am running docker container with 23 images on my macos 12.21 CPU 32GB. When I start my container images starting together but after 3-4mins 4 of them (always the same) stop working, I have to run them again. Any clue why? After that container is running without any troubles.

But my main question is, on this images I have apps written in java with spring framework and all goodies which are coming with it. I am developing separate application which is using the apps via REST queries. I have few simple test in my app I working on, that checking if the data are correct. I can run the tests normally but randomly the apps (docker apps) stop responding and I cannot do nothing. Even if I restart docker(container) apps not always respond straight away. I look into the logs which does not contain much useful information. (I cannot paste the logs here cause it contain other information which should not be public.)

The apps are not very complex I mean it is just simple REST apps where I am sending json and get response with json.

So I wonder is there is something can be done with docker? Cause I am not able to do anything with apps running on docker since I am on the other team, even if I wanted I am not sure where to start looking, cause like I say logs gives no hint why apps stop responding and why it is not responding after container restart.

It will be very helpful if someone will tell me that how to work with docker and how I can debug the app. I am new to docker and so far I have to just run container and write app on local machine. So any tips and trick will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If you run 23 containers on your computer, my guess is that you exhaust the available hardware resources. If your OS is running out of RAM, it will start killing processes that are using a lot of RAM. This can cause containers to be killed without any messages being added to your log explaining what happened.

Maybe those 4 containers hit the limit on your hardware resources, causing your OS to kill the processes? Have a look at `docker stats` to see how much ram is allocated to each container, and make sure that the total allocation is possible on your computer. If the allocation is high, use e.g. `docker update --memory=<size> --memory-swap=<size> <container-name>` to introduce caps on memory for each container. Also consider whether it's reasonable to run that many containers simultaneously on your computer.

It can also be the opposite if you allocate to little RAM for a container. If the container hits the limit, the container will be killed.